# Is there a subword function in SAS?

Tags: sas

I know there is a substring function in SAS but is there a function that returns the first n words from a string?

Comment: this seems like a hack so im not posting as an answer, but this should work `first3 = catx(scan(string,1)," ",scan(string,2)," ",scan(string,3));`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a single function that does exactly this.  You could use a composition of functions like scott offered, or you could go down the regular expression rabbit hole and do something like this, where the number in the braces is the number of words you want:

```
substring = prxchange('s/((\w+ ){2}).*/\1/',-1,original_string);
```

This assumes your words are made up of alphanumeric characters and they're separated by spaces.  (There are probably lots of other special cases that could break it too.)

Answer (score 2):

With SAS 9.2 and beyond, you roll your own function with PROC FCMP.  This will allow you to encapsulate the loop and scan others mention into a form that is reusable in any data step.

```
options cmplib=work.fns;

proc fcmp outlib=work.fns.fns;
function nwords(str $, n) $;
    nstr = countw(str);
    if nstr <= n then do;
        return (str);
    end;
    else do;
        attrib outStr length=$200;
        outStr = "";
        do i=1 to n;
            outStr = strip(outStr) || " " || scan(str,i);
        end;
        return (outStr);
    end;
endsub;
run;
quit;

data test;
str = "I went to the store to get milk and bread.";
format substrs $200.;
do i=1 to 5;
    substrs = nwords(str,i);
    output;
end;
run;
```

Comment: I considered answering that, but I would caution that `PROC FCMP` is not very efficient, in particular at something like this - it's slower or the same (at best) as the identical datastep code, and in some instances is a LOT slower, due to SAS being able to take some shortcuts with data step code that it can't with FCMP functions.

Comment: @Joe, I agree.  Unless you are dealing with a super large data set, or something where fractions of a second matter, then this should be OK.  Otherwise I would roll this in a macro.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a subword function directly.  You can use CALL SCAN, however, to find out where the word is located.

```
%let words=4;
data _null_;
infile datalines truncover;
input @1 text $500.;
position=0;
length=0;
do _t = 1 to &words;
call scan(text,_t,position,length);
end;
newvar = substr(text,1,position+length);
put _all_;
datalines;
The rain in Spain falls mainly in the plains
Spruce Goose is on the loose
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
;;;;
run;
```

The direct solution suggested in the comments (looping around function scan calls) is easier to write, while this avoids calls to CATX (or similar) in putting the words back together and so may perform faster in some instances.